# PHP MySQL insert integer with thousand seperator

Tags: php, mysql, database, int

I have a PHP code that will insert integer numbers with thousand separator into the database. However, it could not save the whole integer..
Exp: 10,234,234  <-- Will only appear as 10 in the database.
     5,434 <- Appear as 5

My code:

```
 <html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$date =  $_SESSION['storeDate'];
$a = $_SESSION['storeA'];
$l = $_SESSION['storeL'];
$p = $_SESSION['storeP'];
$m = $_SESSION['storeM'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

    mysql_select_db("productno", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO records (Date, A, L, P, M)
    VALUES
    ('$date', '$a', '$l', '$p', '$m')"; 

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Save Failed.')
        window.location.href='main.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
    }else{
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Record Added.')
        window.location.href='main.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I modify it so that it will store the whole number -> 10,234,234
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data type in your column is `INT`, then no matter what you try, it will always be truncated.

If you really want that figure to be inserted, alternatively, you could do it like this:

```
$number = '10,234,234';
$number = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // becomes 10234234
// insert code the rest of the way
```

Sidenote: By the way, try to migrate to the improved extension which is `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and utilize prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Integers can't have dots or commas. You have to save it without them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number_format()`:

```
$num = 1999.9;
$formattedNum = number_format($num)."<br>";
echo $formattedNum;
```

Result:

```
2,000
```